# TypeError: Cannot set property localStorage of #<Window> which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, local-storage, fetch-mock

I am mocking localStorage in unitests like

```
function storageMock() {
    var storage = {};
    ....
}
```

and setting localStorage like

```
window.localStorage = localStorageMock()
```

It was working fine until, I have updated Node to `10.15.1`.

It is throwing error that `TypeError: Cannot set property localStorage of #<Window> which has only a getter`.

Any idea that how I can mock localStorage and set it to window.localStorage.

P.S I am getting answers like `setItem` and `getItem` on localStorage, is there any way that I can set whole localStorage at once.

Comment: I met same issue with 10.16.3. Still not solved. Any update of your question?

Comment: I got this after upgrading to jsdom 16.4.0 and node 14.13.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
  value: storageMock
});
```

Full example:

```
const localStorageMock = (() => {
  let store = {};

  return {
    getItem(key) {
      return store[key] || null;
    },
    setItem(key, value) {
      store[key] = value.toString();
    },
    removeItem(key) {
      delete store[key];
    },
    clear() {
      store = {};
    }
  };
})();

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
  value: localStorageMock
});

window.localStorage.setItem("KEY", "INPUT")
```